How to Associate Apple App Store Server Notifications with Users in Flutter When transaction_id Is Unavailable?
I'm developing a Flutter application that implements in-app subscriptions using the in_app_purchase plugin. To associate purchases with specific users, I've utilized the applicationUserName parameter with a unique user identifier (UUID) when initiating a purchase:
final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(
  productDetails: firstProduct,
  applicationUserName: _appAccountToken, // Unique user ID
);

Issue 1: Missing User Data in App Store Server Notifications
After a successful purchase, I send the following details to my server:
purchaseID
productID
verificationData
transactionDate
status

However, when Apple sends server notifications (e.g., for subscription renewals, cancellations), these notifications do not include any user-specific information like applicationUserName or user_id. This makes it challenging to map the transaction back to the correct user in my system.
Issue 2: Deprecated verifyReceipt API
Additionally, I've discovered that the verifyReceipt API is deprecated, which further complicates the process of validating receipts and associating them with users securely.
Questions:

Mapping Transactions to Users:


Given that Apple’s server notifications do not include applicationUserName or user-specific identifiers, what is the recommended approach to reliably associate these notifications with the corresponding users in my Flutter app?


Receipt Validation Alternatives:


With the deprecation of the verifyReceipt API, what alternative methods or APIs should I use for receipt validation and ensuring the authenticity of transactions? How can these alternatives aid in mapping transactions to users?

Additional Context:

I'm using the latest version of the in_app_purchase plugin.
My server is built with Node.js.
I've considered implementing server-side receipt validation and maintaining a mapping between purchaseID and user_id, but I'm unsure how to proceed without transaction_id.

What I've Tried:

Setting applicationUserName to a unique and consistent user identifier.
Sending purchaseID and other purchase details to the server upon purchase completion.
Attempting to map purchaseID to users on the server, but Apple’s server notifications lack corresponding identifiers.

Goal:
Establish a secure and reliable method to map Apple App Store server notifications to the correct users in my Flutter application, ensuring accurate subscription management despite the absence of direct user identifiers in the notifications and the deprecation of the verifyReceipt API.
Any insights, recommended practices, or sample implementations would be greatly appreciated!

You can't. Apple intentionally don't let you do this sort of thing.

is there a way i can map a webhook response from the apple server notification with a user you can tell me of @Scrungepipes

I use the in_app_purchase plugin as well. I set the user ID in the PurchaseParam in the Flutter project and I see the user ID in the notification on the server.
In the DecodedPayload.Data.SignedTransactionInfo:
Details: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/appaccounttoken

